# Node JS Promise.all() results naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, naming

Is there a way for assigning a name for each result in the Promisee.all?

Let's say this is my code:

```
Promise.all([getBalls, getKids, getTeams])
.then(function (results) {
    const new_team = doSomething(results[0], results[1],results[2])
    resolve(new_team);
});
```

And I want it to be something like:

```
Promise.all([
    balls: getBalls,
    kids: getKids,
    teams: getTeams
]).then(function (results) {
    const new_team = doSomething(balls,kids,teams)
    resolve(new_team);
});
```

Comment: The API you are asking for looks exactly like Bluebird's `Promise.props()`: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html.  You pass in an object like you specify (except not in an array) and you get back results in an object with the same keys.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 That's really cool but not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What do you mean "not what you're looking for"?  It works exactly how you asked.  `Promise.all()` simply doesn't work the way you asked so you're going to need new code to get a function that does work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ES2015's [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the `.then` callback function:

```
Promise.all([
    getBalls, 
    getKids, 
    getTeams
]).then(function ([ balls, kids, teams ]) { // <= notice the function parameters
    const new_team = doSomething(balls, kids, teams);
    resolve(new_team);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Arnelle Balane

Comment: @HatzavWolff no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In recent node.js ( > `node v6.x`) version, you can use destructuring and do

```
Promise.all([getBalls, getKids, getTeams])
.then(function ([balls, kids, teams]) {
    const new_team = doSomething(results[0], results[1],results[2])
    resolve(new_team);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasThiebaud !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Promise.props looks easier to work with.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html

```
 Promise.props({
   balls: getBalls,
   kids: getKids,
   teams: getTeams
 })
 .then((results) => {
   const new_team = doSomething(results.balls, results.kids, results.teams)
   resolve(new_team);
 });
```